# Teamcity Nuget Publish to Octopus Repository(built in) fails with 503 error

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy, octopus, team-city-10.0

I have an AsP.net Website with nuspec file set up on teamcity.I have basically defined two build steps.
1. Nuget Pack 
2. Nuget Publish.
The nuget package gets created successfully, but I get a 503 error whilst trying to 
run the Nuget publish step.

Here is the teamcity publish settings
[image: publish settings]

the error returned is as follows: 
`[push] An error was encountered when fetching 'PUT https://myoctopusdeployrepo/nuget/packages/'. The request will now be retried.
[10:08:14][push] An error occurred while sending the request.
[10:08:14][push]   The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.`

I know the push to the built in octopus repository works at least for asp.net csharp projects using .csproj and octopack , but i get this error when trying to push a package that was generated from a nuspec file.

Perhaps there is something I'm missing out in the settings ?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst researching and trying out certain other build steps, I came across the 'Octopus Deploy: Push Packages' build step ( Teamcity 2018.2). This runs `octo.exe` which will need to be installed on the build agent(Octopus deploy commandLine tool) . This plugin is available on the octopus deploy website.
the command as listed in the log is as below
`octo.exe push --server http://octopusdeployserver --apikey SECRET --package <package url>`

I hope this helps.